# Assigning literals to pointers

Tags: c++, casting

I know there are millions of similar question on this site, but none points to the topic I am having difficulty in understanding.

I would like to assign an integral literal to an integer pointer like this:

```
int *p=(int []){7} //casting the literal to array so that it would return the address of first element just like string literal.
```

But it gives the error:

> a parenthesized type followed by an initializer list is a non-standard explicit type conversion syntax.

And this code works perfectly in C.

If this type of conversion is illegal in C++ , is there any other way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: What is it about `int x = 7; int* p = &x;` that doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: @noob it is giving me runtime error.(The program goes into non responding"

Comment: @Brian It was just bugging me why we cant assign it this way .

Comment: Avoid using raw pointers in C++. Then this problem would not arise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax

```
int *p=(int []){7};
```

is supported in C99 as well C11, but not in C++.

Options in C++11:

1. Use a plain old array.

   ```
   int p[] = {7};
   ```
2. Use a `std::array`.

   ```
   std::array<int, 1> p = {7};
   ```
3. Use a `std::vector`.

   ```
   std::vector<int> p(1, 7);
   ```

Comment: `(int []){7}` is a *compound literal*; it's supported in both C99 and C11.